# How to use regex with MongoDB's distinct command?

Tags: php, regex, json, mongodb

MongoDB's distinct command is perfect for what I'm trying to achieve, which is get a unique set of results for a particular key in a collection.

I've read that it supports regex, but I can't work out how to incorporate it into the query.

So this:

```
db.runCommand({distinct:'cars',key:'car_company.name'})
```

Would return

```
{
    "values" : [
        "Chevy",
        "Porche",
        "Chevrolet",
        "BMW",
        "Mercedes-Benz",
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "n" : 5,
        "nscanned" : 5,
        "nscannedObjects" : 5,
        "timems" : 0,
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How would I build this query so that it only returns the unique values that match a regex of say, 'chev'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `php` you can achieve this by doing

```
$cars = $db->command(
    array(
        "distinct" => "car_collection",
        "key" => "car_company.name",   // or what so ever key you wish to be distinct
        "query" => array("car_company.name" => new MongoRegex("/^chev/i"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Print_r($cars) returns:

Array ( [values] => Array ( ) [stats] => Array ( [n] => 0 [nscanned] => 5 [nscannedObjects] => 5 [timems] => 0 [cursor] => BasicCursor ) [ok] => 1 )

Comment: Can you provide some code what you tried. Actually I don't use php. I referred to documentation and provided with my solution. I followed http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php